# Highcharts tooltip get position and change class

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have a custom tooltip that I have styled using HTML and headerFormat etc, like so:

```
tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            valueDecimals: 2,
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            borderColor: '#c0c0c0',
            borderRadius: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            xDateFormat: '%d %b %y',
            headerFormat: '<div class="chart-tooltip"><span class="tooltip-header">{point.key}</span><br><div class="markers"><span class="tooltip-bg"></span>',
            pointFormat: '<span class="tooltip-marker" style="background: {series.color};"></span>' +
                '<span class="tooltip-series" style="color: {series.color};">{point.y}</span><br>',
            footerFormat: '</div></div>',
            animation: false,
            shadow: false,
            style: {
                padding: '0px'
            }
        }
```

Using the classes I have then styled the tooltip with my external CSS file. This works well except for one problem, the tooltip looks like this:

[image] So the problem is when the crosshair is over to the left of the chart, the tooltip goes over to the right and the arrow is on the wrong side.

[image]

Is it possible to know when the tooltip changes sides, and then add a class accordingly? So I can then adjust the styles.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would help you, but you can check it:

Check the API of tooltip->positioner: [tooltip.positioner API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner) (if you are using highstock you can use it too)

```
tooltip:{
    positioner:function(boxWidth, boxHeight, point){
        ...
    }
}
```

The default tooltip for highcharts is ([highcharts.js](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js)):

```
/**
 * Place the tooltip in a chart without spilling over
 * and not covering the point it self.
 */

getPosition: function (boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {

// Set up the variables
var chart = this.chart,
    plotLeft = chart.plotLeft,
    plotTop = chart.plotTop,
    plotWidth = chart.plotWidth,
    plotHeight = chart.plotHeight,
    distance = pick(this.options.distance, 12),
    pointX = point.plotX,
    pointY = point.plotY,
    x = pointX + plotLeft + (chart.inverted ? distance : -boxWidth - distance),
    y = pointY - boxHeight + plotTop + 15, // 15 means the point is 15 pixels up from the bottom of the tooltip
    alignedRight;

// It is too far to the left, adjust it
if (x < 7) {
    x = plotLeft + mathMax(pointX, 0) + distance;
}

// Test to see if the tooltip is too far to the right,
// if it is, move it back to be inside and then up to not cover the point.
if ((x + boxWidth) > (plotLeft + plotWidth)) {
    x -= (x + boxWidth) - (plotLeft + plotWidth);
    y = pointY - boxHeight + plotTop - distance;
    alignedRight = true;
}

// If it is now above the plot area, align it to the top of the plot area
if (y < plotTop + 5) {
    y = plotTop + 5;

    // If the tooltip is still covering the point, move it below instead
    if (alignedRight && pointY >= y && pointY <= (y + boxHeight)) {
        y = pointY + plotTop + distance; // below
    }
} 

// Now if the tooltip is below the chart, move it up. It's better to cover the
// point than to disappear outside the chart. #834.
if (y + boxHeight > plotTop + plotHeight) {
    y = mathMax(plotTop, plotTop + plotHeight - boxHeight - distance); // below
}

return {x: x, y: y};
},
```

I found this explain here: [Highcharts tooltip always on right side of cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966286/highcharts-tooltip-always-on-right-side-of-cursor/11975793#11975793), so you can check and play with that option.

Comment: right thanks, yeah I saw this too, but I'm not sure exactly how this can help me with what i need, does this let you see the position of the tooltip and fire an event when it changes side?

Comment: The positioner contains a function, so before of the "return" you can add some code, and you have the position with point.plotX and the size with boxWidth, you can try to calculate. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/bAw5J/80/

Answer (score 0):

This will show tool tip on left corner of high charts:

```
tooltip: {
      useHTML: true, 
      positioner: "function () { return { x: 0, y: 0 }; }"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

user below

```
#container {
    direction:ltr !important;
}
```