# Showing tooltip on right side of the column in a vertical bar chart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have a highchart where I want the tooltip to hover on the right side of the column (vertical bar chart), because currently the top of the chart do not have enough space, so it displays at the bottom of the column.

FYI - I have gone through various sites and found that most of the example are given for line chart where position can be done left or right, not particularly for vertical bar chart where by default cursor position are top or down

[image: Please refer this image]

```
var tooltip = {
                'formatter': function() {
                    var name = this.series.name;
                    if (_.isObject(name)) { // jshint ignore:line
                        name = name.last + ', ' + name.first;
                    }
                    var key = this.key;
                    if (_.isArray(this.key)) { // jshint ignore:line
                        //Multi people search object
                        key = '';
                        for (var i = 0; i < this.key.length; i++) {
                            key += this.key[i].last + ', ' + this.key[i].first + '<br>';
                        }
                    } else if (_.isObject(this.key)) { // jshint ignore:line
                        key = key.last + ', ' + key.first;
                    }
                    var val = chartUtility.handleAddingThousandSeparator(sourcedata, chartUtility.handleRoundingSingleValue(sourcedata, this.point.y));
                    val = chartUtility.prefixSuffix(sourcedata, this.point, val);
                    return '<strong>' + key + '</strong><table>' + '<tr><td style="color: ' + this.series.color + '"> :' + name + ': </td>' + '<td style="text-align: right"><b>' + val + '</b></td></tr>';
                }
            };`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts tooltip always on right side of cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966286/highcharts-tooltip-always-on-right-side-of-cursor)

Comment: I have gone through this as well but found this is the example of the line chart where by default cursor position are right or left, so we can adjust position either on left or right. But, my question was related to vertical bar chart where tooltip cursor position are by default top or down, so if I adjust position of x & y, it would give me result in top or down only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the positionner options you could do this :

```
tooltip: {
positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
  if (point.plotY < 55) { // for highest columns
    return {
      x: point.plotX + 100,
      y: point.plotY + 30
    };
  } else { // others columns
    return {
      x: point.plotX,
      y: point.plotY - 20
    };
  }
},
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/qhacux2g/)

Comment: Thanks for quick response! @Core972